# How can I disable linking against certain frameworks with Qt on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have an app built using QT Creator that requires neither OpenGL or AGL. However for some reason, the Makefile that is created wants to add OpenGL and AGL frameworks to the 'LIBS' variable.

Is there a way to tell the make process not to do so? I tried with the following additions to my project's .pro file:

```
LIBS -= -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
```

and

```
QT -= opengl
```

But neither worked.

I can edit the Makefile after it has been generated and manually remove these frameworks from the LIBS variable and everything links fine.

The top of my .pro file looks like this:

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = gui
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_random

INCLUDEPATH += ../../include \
               /usr/local/include \
               /usr/include
```

Comment: Does it work if you replicate the linker command manually while removing those unwanted options?

Comment: Yes. It works without those linker options

Comment: Can you show the whole command with the unintentional options left in?

Comment: Sure, see http://pastebin.com/GnT51PQX. The two culprit frameworks are right at the very end. Note this is more of a curiosity really as the app compiles and builds fine with the two frameworks added but doesn't appear to require them.

Comment: Have you tried this? `LIBS -= "-framework OpenGL -framework AGL"` or even in two parts? (Btw, I am also from Cambridge. ;-))

Comment: Ha, small world! Thanks for the suggestion but no, unfortunately that didn't work!

Comment: What exactly did not work? Have you tried this? `LIBS -= "-framework"
LIBS -= "OpenGL"
LIBS -= "-framework"
LIBS -= "AGL"`